# Smarty : round up to decimal

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have been looking for few hours now and can't figure out a solution.

I need a way to round up a price to it's upper decimal, in my template (smarty, I can't edit any php file)
I tried with the round function, but can't figure out how to give the mode parameter "PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP".

Here is what I got so far, that makes a standard round

```
{(($x+7.5+($x-15)*0.3)/15)|round:"1"}
```

But it returns 3.2 for x=35 instead of 3.3

Tell me if you need any additional infos.

Comment: Are you trying to use ceil on decimal points, right?

Comment: @sammry Yes you can see it like that, but AFAIK ceil round to integer only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of sleep and here comes a solution !

Instead of looking for a function, I found that nifty use of ceil :

```
{(((($x+7.5+($x-15)*0.3)/15)/0.1)|ceil)*0.1}
```

Simple math, thanks php.net comments !